# how to convert version 2 to version 5

Tags: pine-script

//@version=2

study(title="Volume Based Buy and Sell Momentum by 2tm", shorttitle="VBSM")

EMA_Len = input(25, title="Lenth", minval=1)
xROC = roc(close, 1)

nRes1 = iff(volume < volume[1], nz(nRes1[1], 0) + xROC, nz(nRes1[1], 0))

nRes2 = iff(volume > volume[1], nz(nRes2[1], 0) + xROC, nz(nRes2[1], 0))
nRes3 = nRes1 + nRes2

nResEMA3 = sma(nRes1, EMA_Len) + sma(nRes2, EMA_Len)

PNVI = plot(nRes3, color=blue, title="PVI + NVI")
PEMA = plot(nResEMA3, color=red, title="EMA")

pCol = nRes3 > nResEMA3 ? blue : red

fill (PNVI, PEMA, pCol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use prefix ta before time series related functions like roc and sma. You will have to use suffix like int after input. You have to use prefix like color before colors like red and blue.

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Volume Based Buy and Sell Momentum by 2tm", shorttitle="VBSM")

EMA_Len = input.int(25, title="Lenth", minval=1) 
xROC = ta.roc(close, 1)

var nRes1=0.0
nRes1 := volume < volume[1]? nz(nRes1[1], 0) + xROC: nz(nRes1[1], 0)
var nRes2=0.0
nRes2 := volume > volume[1]? nz(nRes2[1], 0) + xROC: nz(nRes2[1], 0)
nRes3 = nRes1 + nRes2

nResEMA3 = ta.sma(nRes1, EMA_Len) + ta.sma(nRes2, EMA_Len)

PNVI = plot(nRes3, color=color.blue, title="PVI + NVI") 
PEMA = plot(nResEMA3, color=color.red, title="EMA")

pCol = nRes3 > nResEMA3 ? color.blue : color.red

fill (PNVI, PEMA, pCol)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you convert from //@version=2 to //@version=3

Then from //@version=3 to //@version=5 will be done automatically